# Bit field defines for setting CLKPOL and CLKPHA to zero

Tags: embedded, uart

I want to define inside efm32lg controller my USART0->CTRL register that CLKPOL and CLKPHA will be zero as shown in the table bellow, but i could not see the bitfield define for that in the manual bellow.
Where could i get the bit field define for this purpose.
Thanks.

https://docs.silabs.com/mcu/latest/efm32lg/group-USART

https://docs.silabs.com/mcu/latest/efm32lg/group-USART#gga9308807377a9f1b25c19bc60d9f64674a8084853059cd3bfd2fb020299d3da687

[image]
[image]

Comment: If these defines are not provided, you can define them yourself. There are enough examples in the documentation you link to.

Comment: Try a full text search of whatever support code the vendor gave you, or do it yourself.  It's also possible that what they've defined are mode constants combining both rather than the individual bits.  If you don't like how they did it, do what you like.

Answer (score 0):

From the EFM32GG11B code base. This can be seen from the SiLabs studio for the GG11B.

```
//-----------------
spidrvClockMode0
//-----------------
typedef enum SPIDRV_ClockMode{
  spidrvClockMode0 = 0,           ///< SPI mode 0: CLKPOL=0, CLKPHA=0.
  spidrvClockMode1 = 1,           ///< SPI mode 1: CLKPOL=0, CLKPHA=1.
  spidrvClockMode2 = 2,           ///< SPI mode 2: CLKPOL=1, CLKPHA=0.
  spidrvClockMode3 = 3            ///< SPI mode 3: CLKPOL=1, CLKPHA=1.
} SPIDRV_ClockMode_t;
//-----------------
  if ( initData->clockMode == spidrvClockMode0 ) {
    usartInit.clockMode = usartClockMode0;
  }
//-----------------
ConfigGPIO()...
  if ( enable ) {
    if ( handle->initData.type == spidrvMaster ) {
      GPIO_PinModeSet((GPIO_Port_TypeDef)pins.mosiPort, pins.mosiPin,
                      gpioModePushPull, 0);
      GPIO_PinModeSet((GPIO_Port_TypeDef)pins.misoPort, pins.misoPin,
                      gpioModeInput, 0);
      
      if (    (handle->initData.clockMode == spidrvClockMode0)
              || (handle->initData.clockMode == spidrvClockMode1) ) {
        GPIO_PinModeSet((GPIO_Port_TypeDef)pins.clkPort, pins.clkPin,
                        gpioModePushPull, 0);
      } else {
        GPIO_PinModeSet((GPIO_Port_TypeDef)pins.clkPort, pins.clkPin,
                        gpioModePushPull, 1);
      }
//-----------------

  /* Set bits for synchronous mode. */
  usart->CTRL |= (USART_CTRL_SYNC)
                 | (uint32_t)init->clockMode
                 | (init->msbf ? USART_CTRL_MSBF : 0);

//-----------------
```